# Cannot get model includes method to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am getting a weird error and I am not sure how to debug it. I have tried a few different things, but nothing is working.

When I run the following code in my application

```
CoursePresentation.includes(:course)
```

I get the following error

```
[6] pry(main)> CoursePresentation.includes(:course)
  CoursePresentation Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "course_presentations".* FROM "course_presentations"
  Course Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "courses".* FROM "courses"  WHERE "courses"."id" IN (1)
(pry) output error: #<NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass>
```

Any help or a direction that I can go in to solve this. I had it working, but now it's not :/

My code for these models is below

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key= 'id'

  has_many :course_presentations

  validates :name, presence: true
end

class CoursePresentation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
  has_many :interactions

  self.primary_key= 'id'

  validates :course_id, :year, :month, presence: true

  def full_name
    course.name + ' (' + period + ')'
  end

  def period
    year.to_s + month.to_s
  end

  def period_description
    "#{ Date::MONTHNAMES[month.to_i]}, #{year}" 
  end
end
```

Thanks.

Comment: Where's the code that has an each in it?

Comment: Share the controller code where you are calling `CoursePresentation.includes(:course)`

Comment: I have updated the code with my full class. When I call Interaction.includes(:course_presentation) that works fine, but CoursePresentation.includes(:course) doesn't work. Been sitting with this for a couple of ours ...

Comment: I am just calling it directly in the rails console. CoursePresentation and the other classes are all models.

Comment: Note I have stripped down the code to just the models and the associations, so it must be something with the database and the way my migration scripts have run.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.

Doing an inspect on the models showed me that one of my foreign keys was a string. After updating this to an integer all is working.

```
[6] pry(main)> Course.inspect
"Course(id: integer, name: string, is_active: boolean, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)"
[7] pry(main)> CoursePresentation.inspect
"CoursePresentation(id: integer, course_id: string, year: integer, month: integer, is_active: boolean, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, mail_chimp_key: string)"
```

Thanks for the comments, they really helped think in that direction.